# How is Yuneec SDK?

Tags: sdk

Has anyone used Yuneec’s SDK or know anything about it? Building SDK for drones creates a lot of possibilities. But want to see if anyone here has experience with Yuneec before.
http://developer.yuneec.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Yuneec has SDK for both iOS and Android. I am currently looking into the Yuneec Android SDK to design a custom app and so far its been great! The SDK exposes a lot of features and looks like they are going to be adding a lot of exciting features soon. SDK provides APIs to control the Yuneec drones and can be customized to your needs. You can definitely check out more here https://developer.yuneec.com.